# Cloning a git repository: works on Linux, not with Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been using SourceTree for a while, both for remote projects and for projects I have on my git server. Usually I get a path like:

```
<username>@someaddress.com:/path/to/repository
```

Now I have to clone a public repository and the link provided is the following:

```
git://sigrok.org/libserialport
```

I tried to put it in the clone form of SourceTree and I get the following error:

```
This is not a valid source path / url
```

Strange thing is that if I go on a Linux machine and issue the command:

```
git clone git://sigrok.org/libserialport
```

I can clone the repository. How should be the path formed to work with SourceTree?

Comment: Does source tree support the `git://` protocol? You probably want a `http(s)://` repo address

Comment: Possibly a bug too https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Cloning-repository-error-This-is-not-a-valid-source-path-URL-Mac/qaq-p/373372.

Comment: Is there a way to get the http address? The website has a web interface like [this](https://sigrok.org/gitweb/?p=libserialport.git;a=tree) but using that address does not work. Also, just putting `http(s)://` instead of `git://` did not do the trick.

Comment: That depends on your repo, i.e. where and what is hosting it?

Comment: Have you tried another UI tool like Git Extensions? https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/ IMO this is a better tool than Source tree anyway

Comment: Gitextension cloned the repository in a breeze... :\

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of source tree. Sounds like a bug. Source tree is very much optimised for use on atlasian servers. It's also fussy and confusing IMO. GIT Extensions FTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable Mercurial in the Tools -> Options, 
Enabling Mercurial allowed the clone dialogue to correctly identify the repo.